# SwiftUI: Random "Extra argument in call" error

Tags: swiftui, combine

So I'm trying to learn SwiftUI and Combine. I usually start new tech by making a simple tip calculator.

I seem to be getting a random "Extra argument in call." error while coding 
Here is my SwiftUI File

```
import SwiftUI

internal enum ReceiptRowType {
    case subtotal
    case tax
    case total
    case tip
    case grandTotal
}

struct TipView: View {
    @ObservedObject internal var adBannerView: BannerAdView = BannerAdView()
    @ObservedObject internal var receiptViewModel: ReceiptViewModel

    private let percentageFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.numberStyle = .percent
        return f
    }()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .scaledToFit()

            VStack {
                if adBannerView.adHasLoaded {
                    adBannerView
                        .frame(maxHeight: adBannerView.adHeight)
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0))
                }

                BorderView()

                Text(ARCHLocalizedStrings.receipt)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)

                BorderView()

                HStack {
                    Spacer()

                    Button(action: {
                        self.receiptViewModel.addNewReceiptItem()
                    }) {
                        Text(ARCHLocalizedStrings.buttonTitleAddItem)
                    }
                }

                BorderView()

                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(receiptViewModel.receiptItems) { receiptItem in
                        ItemView(receiptItem: receiptItem)

                        if receiptItem != self.receiptViewModel.receiptItems.last {
                            Divider()
                        }
                    }
                }

                BorderView()

                BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                                   type: ReceiptRowType.subtotal,
                                   title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.subtotal)

                BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                                   type: ReceiptRowType.tax,
                                   title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.tax)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, ARCHSwiftUILayoutConstants.defaultPaddingAndSpacing)
        }
    }
}

struct BorderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("================================")
            .lineLimit(1)
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var receiptItem: ReceiptItemViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(receiptItem.name, text: $receiptItem.name)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.leading)

            TextField("Price", value: $receiptItem.price, formatter: ARCHUtilities.currencyFormatter)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.trailing)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .frame(width: ARCHSwiftUILayoutConstants.widthForCurrency)
        }
    }
}

struct BottomOfReceiptRow: View {
    @ObservedObject internal var receiptViewModel: ReceiptViewModel

    internal var type: ReceiptRowType
    internal var title: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()

            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)

            if type == ReceiptRowType.subtotal {
                Text("\(receiptViewModel.subtotal)")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: ARCHSwiftUILayoutConstants.widthForCurrency)
            } else if type == ReceiptRowType.tax {
                Text("\(receiptViewModel.taxRate)")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: ARCHSwiftUILayoutConstants.widthForCurrency)
            } else if type == ReceiptRowType.total {
                Text("\(receiptViewModel.total)")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: ARCHSwiftUILayoutConstants.widthForCurrency)
            } else if type == ReceiptRowType.tip {

            } else if type == ReceiptRowType.grandTotal {
                Text("\(receiptViewModel.grandTotal)")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: ARCHSwiftUILayoutConstants.widthForCurrency)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TipView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TipView(receiptViewModel: ReceiptViewModel())
    }
}
```

However, if I add another view on the TipView body (Any View) I seem to get a "Extra argument in call" error.

[Picture of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCAXk.png)

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: try making a Group { } around your views. just 10 are allowed in Swiftui...with group you can add more. or use subviews...(would be cleaner code too)

Comment: This works, I didn't know that there was a limit. But instead of a Group (Group work perfectly) I should probably just rip some of the things into their own view then. Thnx Please write it as the answer and I will make it the official one.

Comment: Both Chris's and SparkleBeard are the right solution.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

try making a Group { } around your views. just 10 are allowed in Swiftui...with group you can add more. or use subviews...(would be cleaner code too)

Comment: just 10 are allowed in Swiftui. It was really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You sir, are correct. Thank you for redeeming the whole day I spent trying to solve this error.

Comment: Thanks Apple for another random limitation... now my code with 11 views, for the sake of "making the code simple and readable" has 22 extra wrapper lines! - thanks for clearing this up. When I noticed this error showed up on the 11th view I immediately suspected another random limitation...

Answer (score 27):

The @ViewBuilder system in SwiftUI is limited to 10 views within any given view container. There's no argument for an 11th view, so you get that error.

## Basic solution:

The issue here is that your VStack is at maximum capacity, however you can wrap those existing views inside of other containers. As a very basic example that would allow you to show 10 `BottomReceiptRow` views:

```
    var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.white
            .scaledToFit()

// Modifications start here

        VStack {
            if adBannerView.adHasLoaded {
                adBannerView
                    .frame(maxHeight: adBannerView.adHeight)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0))
            }

            BorderView()

            Text(ARCHLocalizedStrings.receipt)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)

            BorderView()

            HStack {
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    self.receiptViewModel.addNewReceiptItem()
                }) {
                    Text(ARCHLocalizedStrings.buttonTitleAddItem)
                }
            }

            BorderView()

            ScrollView {
                ForEach(receiptViewModel.receiptItems) { receiptItem in
                    ItemView(receiptItem: receiptItem)

                    if receiptItem != self.receiptViewModel.receiptItems.last {
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }

            BorderView()

            Group {
                BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                                   type: ReceiptRowType.subtotal,
                                   title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.subtotal)

                BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                                   type: ReceiptRowType.tax,
                                   title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.tax)

                BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                                   type: ReceiptRowType.someValue,
                                   title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue)

                BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                                   type: ReceiptRowType.someValue2,
                                   title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue2)

                BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                                   type: ReceiptRowType.someValue3,
                                   title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue3)

                BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                                   type: ReceiptRowType.someValue4,
                                   title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue4)

                BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                                   type: ReceiptRowType.someValue5,
                                   title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue5)
            }
// Modifications end here

        }
        .padding(.horizontal, ARCHSwiftUILayoutConstants.defaultPaddingAndSpacing)
    }
}
```

## Alternatively:

You may prefer to completely refactor these sections into their own `View` as composition makes the code easier to read. It's not strictly necessary here though.

If you did want to do that, you could consider an example where those receipt rows are all in their own view like:

```
    var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.white
            .scaledToFit()

        VStack {
            if adBannerView.adHasLoaded {
                adBannerView
                    .frame(maxHeight: adBannerView.adHeight)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0))
            }

            BorderView()

            Text(ARCHLocalizedStrings.receipt)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)

            BorderView()

            HStack {
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    self.receiptViewModel.addNewReceiptItem()
                }) {
                    Text(ARCHLocalizedStrings.buttonTitleAddItem)
                }
            }

            BorderView()

            ScrollView {
                ForEach(receiptViewModel.receiptItems) { receiptItem in
                    ItemView(receiptItem: receiptItem)

                    if receiptItem != self.receiptViewModel.receiptItems.last {
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }

            BorderView()

            bottomRow
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, ARCHSwiftUILayoutConstants.defaultPaddingAndSpacing)
    }
}

// Additional computed property in TipView
var bottomRow: some View {
    Group {
        BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                           type: ReceiptRowType.subtotal,
                           title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.subtotal)

        BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                           type: ReceiptRowType.tax,
                           title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.tax)

        BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                           type: ReceiptRowType.someValue,
                           title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue)

        BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                           type: ReceiptRowType.someValue2,
                           title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue2)

        BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                           type: ReceiptRowType.someValue3,
                           title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue3)

        BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                           type: ReceiptRowType.someValue4,
                           title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue4)

        BottomOfReceiptRow(receiptViewModel: receiptViewModel,
                           type: ReceiptRowType.someValue5,
                           title: ARCHLocalizedStrings.someValue5)
    }
} // end bottomRow
```

Comment: this is still true with Xcode 13.4 and swift 5.6.1

Answer (score 3):

In SwiftUI you can stack up to 10 views in the same Stack (VStack, HStack, ZStack), so you can Embed some Views inside another Stack or inside Group {}.